# Can I submit an abstract with a dual affiliation even if one of the two institutions has not contributed to the research submitted?

Tags: conference, affiliation, abstract

I need to submit two abstracts in a conference on behalf of two different institutions. The profile information of the abstract submission system provides only one institution as the primary one. During abstract submission, I am able to report a second affiliation.
How should I deal with this situation. I thought to create two login accounts, but then I am afraid if both abstracts accepted, I will need to register twice.
Alternatively, I thought to include both affiliations in the abstracts and have as the first one my current affiliation. What is the common practice in this case?

Comment: Ask the conference chair or the program chair. I doubt that there is a "common practice" for a rare situation.

Comment: Thank you very much! you are right, it is the best to check with the program chair. I have just emailed, let see what he will reply...